# warning on transactional method after one hour and service didn't work

Tags: transactions, quarkus

i migrated quarkus from 2.7.1 to 3.1.2. all of system worked perfectly for one hour but i got below warning on transactional method and service didn't work after one hour. what is problem? (this method worked in quarkus 2.7.1)

**my service code:**
@Transactional
public GenerateOtpResponse generateOtp(GenerateOtpRequest request) {

```
    Optional<Otp> optional = otpRepository.findNotExpiredOtpWithPessimisticWriteLock(
            request.getMobileNumber()
    );

    Otp otp = Otp.builder()
            .mobileNumber(request.getMobileNumber())
            .otp(codeGenerator.generateOtp(6))
            .expirationTime(calculateExpiredTime(otpUsage))
            .creationTime(new Date())
            .build();

    sendOtp(request.getMobileNumber(),newOtp)

    otpRepository.persistAndFlush(otp);
}

private void sendSms(String mobileNumber, String otp) {  
         smsClient.sendSms(mobileNumber,otp)
}


    -----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,378 TID: ***
ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check processing TX 0:ffffac120005:a39c:64b751e6:540 in state RUN
-----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,379 TID: ***
ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffffac120005:a39c:64b751e6:540 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
-----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,380 TID: ***
ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffffac120005:a39c:64b751e6:540 completed with multiple threads - thread executor-thread-6 was in progress with java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3463)
java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3434)
java.base@17.0.7/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:391)
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$300(AbstractConnPool.java:70)
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:253)
org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:198)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:306)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:282)
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:344)
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:427)
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:134)
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:103)
org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:61)
jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy84.sendSms(Unknown Source)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.client.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:168)
jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy87.sendSms(Unknown Source)
...
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:30)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:27)
ir.co.isc.mss.authentication.app.controllers.AuthenticationOtpController_Subclass.generateOtpForActivation(Unknown Source)
ir.co.isc.mss.authentication.app.controllers.AuthenticationOtpController_ClientProxy.generateOtpForActivation(Unknown Source)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor87.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:154)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:118)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:560)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:452)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:413)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker$$Lambda$858/0x00000008018141c8.get(Unknown Source)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:378)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:356)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:70)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:429)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:240)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher$$Lambda$856/0x0000000801810b40.run(Unknown Source)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:154)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher$$Lambda$857/0x0000000801811450.get(Unknown Source)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:321)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:157)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
-----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,380 TID: ***
ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action 0:ffffac120005:a39c:64b751e6:540 aborting with 1 threads active!
-----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,382 TID: ***
HHH000451: Transaction afterCompletion called by a background thread; delaying afterCompletion processing until the original thread can handle it. [status=4]
-----------------------<<<>>>-----------------------
[WARN] *** 2023-07-19 06:56:57,382 TID: ***
ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully canceled TX 0:ffffac120005:a39c:64b751e6:540
-----------------------<<<*>>>-----------------------

Caused by: jakarta.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016102: The transaction is not active! Uid is 0:ffffac12000e:852b:64abece2:be8
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1285)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:128)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.NotifyingTransactionManager.commit(NotifyingTransactionManager.java:70)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.endTransaction(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:406)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:175)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:107)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:61)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
```